# Pipes in Snakemake: how to share resources between rules?

Tags: pipe, snakemake

My regular way of piping, partially based upon [this Biostars post](https://www.biostars.org/p/43677/), is the following:

```
rule map:
    input: "{sample}.fq.gz",
    output: "sort/{sample}.bam"
    threads: 24
    shell:
        """
bwa mem reference.fa {input} \
-t {threads} | \
samtools sort - \
-@ {threads} \
-o {output}
        """
```

I was keen to try out Snakemake's pipes, as I hoped that they might make workflows with multiple pipes more readable.

```
rule map:
    input: "{sample}.fq.gz",
    output: pipe("{sample}.bam")
    threads: 24
    shell:
        """
    bwa mem reference.fa {input} \
    -t {threads} \
    > {output}
        """

rule sort:
    input: "{sample}.bam"
    output: "sort/{sample}.bam"
    threads: 24
    shell:
        """
samtools sort {input} -@ {threads} -o {output}
        """
```

However, this results in the following `WorkflowError: Job needs threads=48 but only threads=24 are available. This is likely because two jobs are connected via a pipe and have to run simultaneously. Consider providing more resources (e.g. via --cores).`

So I have to divide the threads between bwa and samtools, but allocating threads to samtools means removing threads from bwa and I would prefer not to do this. This problem would become more pronounced in workflows with multiple piping steps.

I have not seen Snakemake pipes used so much, but I'm wondering if anyone knows a workaround? I am also considering to raise this as an issue at Snakemake's Github page.

---

Also, a general question about pipes. Is there a valid reason for Snakemake to allocate separate threads to processes in a pipe? Should I worry about both bwa and samtools using 24 threads in my regular way of piping?

Comment: "Is there a valid reason for Snakemake to allocate separate threads to processes in a pipe?": I'm not a UNIX expert, but I think this is necessary: the processes on both sides of a pipe need their own threads.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I worry about both bwa and samtools using 24 threads in my regular way of piping?

Yes; if only 24 threads can run in parallel on your hardware, it isn't possible (with either kind of pipe) to run 48 threads and be any more efficient than if you were running only 24. The only difference I see is that Snakemake tells you this, whereas the Unix pipe just does the best it can.

If you think dividing the threads evenly is likely to be inefficient somehow (perhaps if one of the two processes will be working much harder in the first half of the file, and then the other will be working much harder in the second half of the file, or something like that), you might consider just running one at a time and writing the intermediate result to disk.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider not to use pipes at all. Reasons to avoid:

1. It is a nightmare when you need to debug. If first job throws an error and you are not handling stderr properly then exception message is lost.
2. If second job in the pipe fails you need to repeats the first one as well, in this case alignment is much more expensive.
3. It is easier to distribute resources and avoid bottlenecks in execution.

The only benefit that I see is that no temp file is needed.